# How to keep changing commandbutton name after every clicks

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My question is for example,I have a button named "A", after i click it will change the button name to "B", and if I click again will change back to "A" and keep changing between "A" and "B" when clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could also use [PrimeFaces's BooleanButton](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/booleanButton.xhtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle a boolean in action method and check in button's value that boolean state.

```
private boolean toggle;

public void toggle() {
    toggle = !toggle;
}

public boolean isToggle() {
    return toggle;
}
```

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bean.toggle ? 'B' : 'A'}" action="#{bean.toggle}">
    <f:ajax render="@this" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: but i have a problem is, it will keep refreshing my whole page. is it any way to only refresh that button instead of whole page?

Comment: WOW!! thanks alot!! this really surprise me!
thanks for ur answer!!